# Secret key has missing trust [sic] in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, snap, gnupg, enigmail

I have recently installed the latest version of Thunderbird (60.3.0, 64-bit) on Ubuntu 18.04 from the Snap Store. I have installed the Enigmail addon and successfully imported my private key. On startup of Thunderbird a notification is displayed:

[image: Enigmail Information]

> Your secret key [...] has missing trust. 
>   We recommend that you set "You rely on certifications" to ultimate in key properties.

After opening “Key Properties” I find no option to set "You rely on certifications". 
[image: Key Properties]

After clicking “Certify” a notification is displayed:

[image: No eligible key found for signing]

> No eligible key found for signing! You need at least one fully trusted secret key in order to sign keys.

How can I resolve this missing trust issue?

**UPDATE**

Following @dlakomski's [advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/1099738/563581) I tried to change the trust setting on my private key (part of `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`), but found it already to be set to `5 = I trust ultimately`.

```
gpg> save
Key not changed so no update needed.
```

Enigmail has found GnuPG in `/snap/thunderbird/29/usr/bin/gpg2` and “Override with `/usr/bin/gpg`” is not an option (probably because Thunderbird was installed as a snap):

> GnuPG cannot be executed with the path provided. Enigmail is therefore deactivated until you change the path to GnuPG again or until you restart the application.

Is it possible that `/snap/thunderbird/29/usr/bin/gpg2` is agnostic to trust settings of keys in `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`?

Comment: I have found no solution for this problem with the snap package. I have dodged the problem by installing the [Thunderbird package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mail/thunderbird) via apt.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
gpg --edit-key 'Your key'
```

Then you should see something like that:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4; Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

sec  rsa4096/0xF759E5159BD8ADB0
     created: 2017-07-13  expires: never     usage: SC
     trust: never         validity: unknown
ssb  rsa4096/0x0FDF21CEA632F8D7
     created: 2017-07-13  expires: never     usage: E
[ unknown] (1). Name Surname <email@address.com>
gpg >
```

Then type:

```
trust
```

which shows:

```
Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision?
```

This is your key, so choose option `5` and exit the program.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but no luck. See update in my post. :-(

Comment: Your answer was helpful but does not answer the question in the situation described above. I will therefor not accept this answer at this point.

Comment: Doesn't work too… trust total (5) => I still have the message